# Поиск файла в (суб-)директории (php)

Tags: php

Данная функция просматривает директорию на наличие файла. Если файл найден - возвращает путь до него. Дело в том что в строке:

```
if( is_file( $directory . '/' . $filename ) ) { echo 'fsd'; return $directory . '/' . $filename;}
```

при нахождении файла в той же папке функция возвращает значение. Но если файл находится в папке путь не возвращается, хотя команда echo показывает fsd. И если я напишу так:

```
if( is_file( $directory . '/' . $filename ) ) { echo $directory . '/' . $filename; return $directory . '/' . $filename;}
```

echo отобразит путь а функция его не возвратит. Ниже код самой функции:

```
public static function search( $directory , $filename = null ) {

// ПРОВЕРКА СУЩЕСТВОВАНИЯ УКАЗАННОЙ ДИРЕКТОРИИ...

    if(!is_dir($directory)) return null;

// ЕСЛИ ИСКОМЫЙ ФАЙЛ НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕН - ВОЗВРАЩАЕМ
// ЛИШЬ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩУЮ ДИРЕКТОРИЮ

    if(!$filename) return $directory;

// ПОИСК ФАЙЛА (ВКЛЮЧАЕТ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ ПОДДЕРИКТОРИИ)

    $opendirectory = opendir( $directory );

    while ( ( $file = readdir( $opendirectory ) ) !== false) {

        if( $file == "." || $file == ".." ) continue;

// ЕСЛИ ФАЙЛ С ЗАДАННЫМ ИМЕНЕМ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ - ВОЗВРАЩАЕМ ПУТЬ

        if( is_file( $directory . '/' . $filename ) ) { echo 'fsd'; return $directory . '/' . $filename;}

// ЕСЛИ ФАЙЛ НЕ ОБНАРУЖЕН - УЕЛИЧИВАЕМ ГЛУБИНУ ПОИСКА

        if( is_dir( $directory . '/' . $file ) ) self::search( $directory . '/' . $file , $filename );

    }
  closedir($opendirectory);
}
```

Вызываем функцию:

echo $filemanager->search( 'page' , 'index.php' );

Бьюсь уже 2 часа...покажите где я накосячил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косяк вот в этой строчке:

```
if( is_dir( $directory . '/' . $file ) ) self::search( $directory . '/' . $file , $filename );
```

Возврат self::search() куда делся?

Comment: спасибо, заработало!!! иногда не замечаешь таких мелочей=)

p.s. сейчас прогнал скрипт...и оказалось что он заработал, но не так как задумывалось. с изменением return self::search(), скрипт показывает не все дерево в каталоге а открывает только первую папку и останавливается. если без return он выдавал, к примеру

page1 
file1.php 
file2.php 
new4.txt 
page2 
index.php 
local.txt 
page_3 
te.txt 
testt.txt

то сейчас:

page1 
file1.php 
file_2.php 
new4.txt

как лечить?

Comment: доделал скрипт...нужно было только изменить так

   if( is_dir( $directory . '/' . $file ) ) $recursion = self::search( $directory . '/' . $file , $filename );
   if($recursion) return $recursion;
еще раз спасибо klopp за подсказку. Тема закрыта!